# Jmeter - throughput is lower than total transaction per second

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I need an advice here. I'm running a performance test using Jmeter. I added Aggregate Report listener and see under throughput value is 8.2/sec.
[image]

But my actual Hits per second is higher than that using a "Hits per second" listener.
[image]

Also, when I generate a report after test run I see "Total Transactions Per Second" graph almost matches to "Hits per second" listener **but not a throughput from Aggregate report.**
[image]

**Questions** why my throughput value does not match to "Total Transactions Per Second"? Is Throughput measures something different here? Can I generate a graph that will represent a "throughput" values from Aggregate report?
According to [Apache doc](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report):

- Throughput - the Throughput is measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.

Any help appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: I think it's obvious. In Aggregate report, throuhput is (total request) / (total time), in both chart, it's throughput over time. And you're comparing max throughput in a short period with throughput in whole time. It looks like you compare max score with average score.

Answer (score 1):

1. "jp@gc  - Hits per Second" is not a part of JMeter, if you want an explanation how does it calculate the metric you need to inspect [its source code](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/tree/master/graphs/graphs-additional) or [contact plugin developers and/or maintainers](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins).
2. Your test runs for 10 seconds and your reporting granularity is set to 1 minute

   [image]

   the plugin you're trying to compare the chart with uses granularity of 1 second so if you want to correlate the charts you should either increase the plugin's granularity of decrease JMeter's HTML Reporting Dashboard granularity. The latter can be done by manipulating `jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity` JMeter property, see [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) article for more information on JMeter Properties and the ways of setting and/or overriding them